# cakephp css/js not load

Tags: apache, cakephp-2.6

I am using cakephp 2.6.2 in ubuntu 16.04 . I enabled mod_rewrite in my system. I downgrade php 7 to php 5.6 .In my cakephp program css and js are not loading

```
 <script src="/admin/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

it not take the project name along with the src

The project need **index.php** in the url
Sessions are not working.
I dont know any other configuration is needed in apache

```
$this->redirect('/notifications/index/');
```

returns *localhost/notifications/index/* instead of *localhost/projectfolder/notifications/index/*

**I got Solution**

My .htaccess is not load by apache. I mention "AllowOverride All" in my virtual host configuration. now it is working fine

Comment: I reslove the issue . My .htaccess is not load by apache. I mention "AllowOverride All"   in my virtual host configuration. now it is working fine